# The minimum number of groups for any class cannot be less than 2 error

Tags: python, data-mining, cross-validation

```
cv_split = StratifiedShuffleSplit(n_splits=10, test_size=0.3, random_state=0)

# Performing cross-validation to estimate the performance of the models
for idx, est in enumerate(estimator):

    cv_results = cross_validate(est[1](), x_value, y_value, cv=cv_split)
```

I got following error from this code

> ValueError: The least populated class in y has only 1 member, which is
>   too few. The minimum number of groups for any class cannot be less
>   than 2.

and my y_value looks like 
`y_value = array([221900, 180000, 510000, ..., 360000, 400000, 325000])`

I used this method before and y_value has the same shape as before.

Comment: Is it solved? I encounter the similar problem?